# parameter estimation of a mixture distribution

Tags: estimation, mixture-distribution, lognormal-distribution

I have this mixture distribution

$f(x) =w \cdot \mathcal{LN}(\mu_1,\sigma) + (1-w)\cdot \mathcal{LN}(\mu_2,\sigma) $

where $\mathcal{LN}(\mu,\sigma)$ is a lognormal distribution.

I now have $j$ random variables

$ Y^{(m)} = \sum_{i=0}^n X_i $ where all $X_i$ are distributed according to $f(x)$ and $m=1,..,j $.

How can I get the maximum likelihood estimation for the unknown paramters $\mu_1, \mu_2$ and $\sigma$ (w is given)? We can also assume that $n$ is a small number, for example $n=10 and j=100$.

Are there other methods of finding the parameters?

Comment: Upon taking the logarithms of the data, [the many methods applicable to Normal mixtures](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=maximum+likelihood+normal+mixture) become available to you.

Comment: @whuber can you elaborate this a bit? Say I generate some data X's according to f(x), sum them to Y, take the log of Y and then I can fit a MLE of a normal mixture and get the same mu and sigma as in f(x)? In my real world apllication of this problem I don't have access to the X's, only the Y's.

Comment: I do not follow you.  What are your data: are they the $n+1$ values of the $X_i$ or are they the *single* value of $Y$ that is mentioned? If all you have is a single $Y$, then you cannot estimate four parameters!

Comment: @whuber I have 100 Y's and I know that each Y is the sum of 10 X's.

Comment: That's a crucial change: please edit your question to make this information explicit.